# pg_fetch_assoc returns boolean

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I'm making a script to insert/update data from a mysql database to a postgres database.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $postgres = "SELECT * FROM res_partner";
    echo $postgres . "\n";
    $pgresult = pg_query($db,$postgres);

    $a = 0;

    if(pg_num_rows($pgresult) > 0)
    {
      while($pgrow = pg_fetch_assoc($pgresult))
      {
        if($pgrow["id"] == $row["customer_id"])
        {
          $a + 1; 
        }
        else
        {
          $a + 0;
        }
      }
      var_dump($pgrow);
      exit();
```

I want to check if the id in mysql database is also in the postgres database. 
But the $pgrow returns "bool(false)" with my var_dump. 
I have no idea why.

Comment: After the last row, `pg_fetch_assoc()` will return false to indicate that there are no more rows to fetch. From the documentation: _FALSE is returned if row exceeds the number of rows in the set, there are no more rows, or on any other error._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `var_dump()` is outside the while loop.

The loop will continue to call `pg_fetch_assoc` until it returns false

Place the call inside the loop to see the contents of the current row:

```
while($pgrow = pg_fetch_assoc($pgresult))
{
    if($pgrow["id"] == $row["customer_id"])
    {
        $a + 1; 
    }
    else
    {
        $a + 0;
    }
    var_dump($pgrow);
}
```

Or use a proper debugger like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) to avoid having to write code like this

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like `SELECT true FROM res_partner WHERE id = $customer_id` so as not to do the while loop?

Then you would get either one row with a single value `true` if it exists, or `false` because no rows were returned.